# fs-stat give value out - Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

my problem is that I want to have the processing time outside the fs-stat-function.
How do I achieve this?
With async that does not work, or how would you do that?

```
var time;
time = fs.stat(path, function(err, stats){  
  timestamp = stats.mtimeMs;
  console.log(timestamp); // 65463453
  return timestamp;
});
```

How can I get the result from the "function(err,stats)" of "fs-stat" in the variable "time"?

Comment: where do you want to use this value?
Best way to use this you can create a promise then call from any function.

Comment: @SayedTauseefHaiderNaqvi I want to use this value in the function that is outside around

and how can I make a promise out of that?

Comment: show you function code from you use this value

Comment: remove your comment from answers and update in your question so that other people will also understand the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code like this and call `getTime` function with promise and you will get the value.

```
var fs = require('fs');
function getTime(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            return resolve(stats.mtimeMs);
        });
    })
}
```

call function like this

```
getTime('./').then(function (timestamp) {
    console.log(timestamp)
})
```

Comment: i tested it, but this code doesnt work =( when i give it out comes "undifined"

Comment: @gegner1111 fixed

Comment: @SayedTauseefHaiderNaqvi next problem ... with the way you showed me, the time is only accessible within the "then" block. Is there a way to use the time outside this block?

Comment: @gegner1111 Can you please share your code where you want to use this value so that I can better understand your uses.

Comment: @SayedTauseefHaiderNaqvi i have fixed it. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

@SayedTauseefHaiderNaqvi

This is the complete code:

```
function getTime(path) {

   var fs = require('fs');
   var time;
   time = fs.stat(path, function(err, stats){  
     timestamp = stats.mtimeMs;
     console.log(timestamp); //65463453
     return timestamp;
   });
   console.log(time); //undefined
   return time;
 }
```